# Finding all solutions to an integer programming problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Given a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^7_{> 0}$, I have the following inequalities:

$$\begin{array}{l}
  a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4 < a_5 < a_6 < a_7\\
  a_7 < a_1 + a_2\\
  a_6 + a_7 < a_1 + a_2 + a_3\\
  a_5 + a_6 + a_7 < a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4
\end{array}$$

$[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]$ satisfies the constraints.

Someone said all $\mathbf{a}$ that satisfy the above can be found by adding non-negative weighted sums of the following row vectors to this vector:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{lllllll}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
  2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
  3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
  2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$

Is this correct, and why is this? How were these row vectors obtained?